# Force bazaar client protocol to use servers protocol 2?

Tags: bazaar

I got ubuntu 12.04 with bazaar 2.5.1 and want to access a repository on a bazaar 1.5 server.
The server understands only bazaars protocol version **2** ,but the client tries to connect with version **3**. How can i force the client to use version 2 of the protocol?

error-message:

```
Server does not understand Bazaar network protocol 3, reconnecting.  (Upgrade the server to avoid this.)
```

It seems after several reconnects bazaar switches automatical to the lower version (as mentioned by bialix in his comment) but afterwards it just complains about the branch-format:

```
'error', "Unknown branch format: 'Bazaar Branch Format 7 (needs bzr 1.6)
```

So nothin really gained. Isn't there a way to tell the newer client to behave like an older?

Comment: client tries to connect with max known version (3) and then use lower version (2) if server doesn't understand first version.

Comment: Forcing the client to use an older version of the protocol won't help. The server needs to support the format of the repository you're trying to access (even if you were using an older client, or an older version of the protocol), but it doesn't.

Comment: i'm not quite sure, but it must be the client complaining, that his expected branch format was not understood by the server. The 1.5 server couldn't possible be clairvoyant ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reository format might solve the problem. Try this :

```
bzr init-repo --pack-0.92 myRepo
bzr branch my1.5branch myRepo
```

Comment: It didn't help in the original case, but it was helpful in a similar later case.